# Sum of Fourier Coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Recently, a question was asked on the site on how to approximate some quantity (either integral or series; I forget and am no longer following the post).  But one of the people who provided a good answer used some result on the sum of Fourier coefficients.  I wanted to ask if there is a theorem about sum of Fourier coefficients.  I can't seem to find anything online.

Of course, I'm not referring to Parseval's identity, as that is for the sum of the squares of the coefficients.  Thank you.

Comment: Use that $1 = e^{2 \pi i n \cdot 0}$. Do you see how this combines with the Fourier inversion formula?

Comment: Well, if I use formula $f(0) = a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(n\cdot 0)+b_n\sin(n\cdot 0)$, it appears that $f(0) = a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$.  So, it looks like $f(0)$ is given by sum of its coefficients for its even periodic extension?  Closest thing I can come up with at the moment.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Also, in case of Fourier inversion formula, using your hint, it looks like $f(0) = \int e^{2\pi i\xi \cdot 0}\hat{f}(\xi) d\xi = \int \hat{f}(\xi) d\xi$.  So, sum of coefficients is just $f(0)$?

Comment: Depending on your convention, you have indeed $f(0)=\int\hat f(\xi)\;d\xi$ and $\hat f(0)=\int f(x)\;dx$. There might be some constants in the way you define your FT.

Comment: Right, so there's a factor involving $2\pi$ in there somewhere.  But basically, it only involves $f(0)$ is my understanding.